# Nesting a count

Tags: sql

I would like to know how to put counting query as a variable for the having count(*)

Generally I want this code to return order_IDs where ALL the suborders (within same order_ID, they are differentiated by another keys) have given status

```
select order_id, count(*)
from order     
where status = 10  
group by order_id

having count(*) = X <-- here I want to put a total number of suborders which I can get by following query:


select order_id, count(order_id) from order 
group by order_id
```

How to put this together?

examplary data I'm using is following: (I messed up a little bit here, sub_ids are primary keys in another table and order_id is a foreign but I handled the joins, that's not the problem in this case)

```
order_id = 1  sub_id = 1  status = 10
order_id = 1  sub_id = 2  status = 5
order_id = 1  sub_id = 3  status = 5

order_id = 2  sub_id = 1  status = 10
order_id = 2  sub_id = 2  status = 10
order_id = 2  sub_id = 3  status = 10
order_id = 2  sub_id = 4  status = 10
order_id = 2  sub_id = 5  status = 10

order_id = 3  sub_id = 6  status = 0
order_id = 3  sub_id = 7  status = 10
```

In this case I want this query to return order_id = 2

Comment: Please given an example, both input data and expected results.  I don't understand your written description.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with stack comments, I updated the main post

Comment: Ah, so the table you call `order` is not the order table. Otherwise `order_id` would be its unique key. That had me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        order_id,
        COUNT(*)                                  cnt_all,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 10 THEN 1 END)   cnt_s10
    FROM
        yourTable
    GROUP BY
        order_id
)
    AS order_summary
WHERE
    cnt_all = cnt_s10
```

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I needed

Comment: Accepted now, but "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."
have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated, but . . .

```
select order_id,
       sum(case when status = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_status_10
from order o     
group by order_id
having count(*) = X;
```

Unlike your query, this will return orders where `cnt_status_10` is `0`.  If you want to exclude those:

```
having count(*) = X and cnt_status_10 > 0;
```

If your database doesn't allow alias in the `having` clause, then use the full expression.

Answer (score 0):

As this is the suborder table, `order_id` must be not nullable. So `count(order_id)` is just `count(*)`.

This means you are looking for orders that only contain status 10 suborders (count for status 10 = total count). That is simply:

```
select order_id, count(*)
from suborder     
group by order_id
having count(case when status = 10 then 1 end) = count(*);
```

(I've renamed the table in my query, so as to avoid confusion with a non-unique `order_id`.)